# Why does this run?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am developing in NetBeans and want to know why does this code run when I press F6? I have no main method. When I press F6, the code runs the method LoadListings and loads the arraylist from "houses.txt" located on my hard drive. It does not run the LoadArray method just before, so only the text file data is printed at the end.

```
package housetracker;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class HouseList {

List<House> houseList;
private String defaultFileName = "houses.txt";
private String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
private String workingDirectory = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + this.fileSeparator);
private String listingsFile = workingDirectory + "txt_files" + this.fileSeparator +  defaultFileName;
private BufferedReader br;
private FileReader fr;
private String line;
private Integer address;
private String street;
private double price;
private int rooms;
DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

public HouseList() {
    houseList = new ArrayList();

}

public void FillArray() {
    fillArray();
}

private void fillArray() {
    houseList.add(new House(123, "Main", 75000.00, 2));
    houseList.add(new House(621, "Mystreet", 175000.00, 5));
    houseList.add(new House(4568, "1st", 725000.00, 8));
    houseList.add(new House(5546, "Broadway", 85600.00, 3));
    houseList.add(new House(8744, "Texas", 195610.00, 6));
    houseList.add(new House(45454, "Maine", 125000.00, 4));
    houseList.add(new House(4465, "Main", 375000.00, 2));
}

public void LoadListings(String fileName) {
    loadListings("C:\\\\temp\\houses.txt");
}
//Load the listings file into the array.

private void loadListings(String fileName) {
    // Clear variables
    this.br = null;
    this.fr = null;
    this.line = null;

    try {
        // Set FileReader to access the user specified file name.
        this.fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        System.out.println(fr);
        // Use a BufferedReader to load file into memory.
        this.br = new BufferedReader(this.fr);
        System.out.println(br);
        System.out.println("*****************************************************\n");

        // Read file contents a line at a time until file returns null.
        while ((line = this.br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            // Let StringTokenizer parse each line and split data into elements 
            // using an empty space as the separator.  
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

            // Loop through each each element of the line 
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                this.address = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
                this.street = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                this.price = Double.parseDouble(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
                this.rooms = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
                // Format price to look like money.
                moneyFormat.format(this.price);

                // Build a string just because I can
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("*******************");
                sb.append("\nAddress    : ").append(this.address);
                sb.append("\nStreet  : ").append(this.street.toUpperCase());
                sb.append("\nPrice : ").append(this.price);
                sb.append("\nRooms       : ").append(this.rooms);
                sb.append("\n*******************");
                System.out.println(sb.toString());

                // Add data to array
                houseList.add(new House(this.address, this.street, this.price, this.rooms));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");
        System.out.println("Array is loaded");
        // Set a variable indicating array is loaded and ready for transactions.
        //this.isArrayLoaded = true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Catch any IO errors while accessing the file and alert the user.
        System.out.println("An IO error occured while accessing " + fileName + ". Operation terminated.\n\n" + e);
        //this.isArrayLoaded = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close file operations
            if (this.br != null) {
                this.br.close();
                this.fr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n\n" + ex + "\n");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    //return this.isArrayLoaded;
}

public void showHouses() {
    Iterator<House> itr = houseList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
    }
}
}
```

And this class...

```
package housetracker;

public class House {
private int address;
private String street;
private double price;
private int rooms;

public House(int address, String street, double price, int rooms) {
    this.address = address;
    this.street = street;
    this.price = price;
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

public void SetAddress (int address){
    setAddress(address);
}

private void setAddress (int address){
    this.address = address;
}

public void SetStreet (String street){
    setStreet(street);
}

private void setStreet(String street){
    this.street = street;
}

public void SetPrice (double price){
    setPrice(price);
}

private void setPrice (double price){
    this.price = price;
}

public void SetRooms(int rooms){
    setRooms(rooms);
}

private void setRooms(int rooms){
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

public int GetAddress (int address){
    address = getAddress(address);
    return address;
}

private int getAddress (int address){
    return address;
}

public String GetStreet (String street){
    street = getStreet(street);
    return street;
}

private String getStreet(String street){
    return street;
}

public double GetPrice (double price){
    price = getPrice(price);
    return price;
}

private double getPrice (double price){
    return price;
}

public int GetRooms(int rooms){
    rooms = getRooms(rooms);
    return rooms;
}

private int getRooms(int rooms){
    return rooms;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return address + " " + street + " " + price + " " + rooms;
}
}
```

Comment: is the code at all relevant to the question?

Comment: @sjr I am questioning why the code runs without a main method, so I think so. Why only the one block of code? Why not all of it? I posted everything so maybe someone can tell me what is going on with it and WHY. How does your comment contribute to this posting?

Comment: What have you tried? Well how about you put a block in before the block that gets run? How is posting a whole crapton of code here supposed to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I get a delete here? I found a main method hiding in another class that wasn't opened in my IDE. I feel like an idiot!

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, Yes: earlier versions of Java seem to let you run an application that doesn't have a "main()".

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/567731/Java/java/we-develop-java-application-without

This behavior is now disallowed in JDK 7 :)

Comment: Can you find a `static` block in OP's code? How is this an answer to the question "Why does this code run"?

Comment: Nope, not a single `static` in my code...